# Tablesorter when data-value attribute is set ajax triggers on initial load

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

when I have `data-value` set on one element, the whole table is loaded from AJAX dispite I have `processAjaxOnInit: false` in the main app.js file (because I have data to table preloaded on the first load).

When I remove this `data-value` attribute, the ajax **is not** triggered on init - this is desireable behavior, but I want this also with that attribute.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle with a working sample?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. I am loading tablesroter with yarn encore, I have ajax script on it and I am developing it on local machine. I dont know how all this goes together with JSFiddle. I am not very familiar with it, if It is even possiblet to use in this case...